# Can I get JSP/ JSF hosting in shared hosting plans?

Tags: web-hosting, web-development, website-design, looking-for-hosting

I want to use JSF with Facelets/JSP in my website. Can I get Java hosting in shared hosting plans ?

I want to re-develop a company website for my client. Currently the website uses PHP & is hosted on Dreamhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you can. [Here's a Google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java%20hosting%20shared%20hosting&qscrl=1) which returns some companies.